# Making PC laptop scrolling smooth like Macbook?

Tags: windows, mac, laptop, mouse

I don't like the jumpy 2-finger scrolling of my Acer laptop. Is there any way to make my PC laptop mouse pad's scrolling as smooth as a Macbook?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about smooth scrolling and your OS is Windows, since you did not specify.

This largely depends on the application.  Each application handles their own scrolling and thus their own scrolling animation.

There is no way to do this system wide.